# Custom Module Magento not showing in second website

Tags: magento

I'm building a custom module for Magento (1.7.1.0) and I need it to support multiple websites, stores and store views. I've got it working on all stores for the first website_id, but somehow it's not working on the second website.

```
Setup:
-> website_id:1
----> store_id:1  works!
----> store_id:2  works!
----> store_id:3  works!
-> website_id:2
----> store_id:4  doesn't work :(
```

All of the "design" code (layout and templates) are in the base/default folder
All of the "code" is in the community folder

Contents of layout.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <catalog_category_layered>
        <reference name="left">
            <remove name="catalog.leftnav"/>
            <block type="catalog/layer_view" name="catalog.betterlayers" before="-" template="betterlayers/layer.phtml" />
        </reference>
    </catalog_category_layered>
</layout>
```

Somehow, the new functionality does not show on the second website.
In fact, the only thing that gets called from my custom module is the _construct() function for the main Block (but that always happens). The template file never gets included anywhere for website_id:2

Can anybody help me out by pointing out possible differences between website_id:1 and website_id:2?

So far, I've ruled out:

- Different design base (both websites use base/default)
- Store specific problems (both websites work fine if I try other modules and I'm using a custom test shop with only this module, some custom website_ids and store_ids, with Magento Sample Data)
- Conflicting design layout xml files
- Magento Cache, Magento Compiler and APC / Memcached

Thanks for your help!

PS: Any info you need that is not provided here, just ask!

Comment: Did you configure the "Design" tab in System/configuration properly ? For each website (or globally) ?

Comment: Yep, thanks for your suggestion. I've already fixed the issue (see my own answer below).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I was just being stupid.

All categories for the second website were not Anchored. The above layout.xml clearly shows that only layered view should include the module template files...